# build.gradle - error deploying artifact

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm having issues with publishing to local nexus maven repository.

I admit, I don't have much experience with using gradle.

I will say that I have tried understanding the documentation and examples that are given through the gradle website (along with a few stackoverflow questions).

I am getting the following error when I try to publish:

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.

> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
   > Error deploying artifact 'com.myproject:myproject-sdk:jar': Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://git.site.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/myproject/myproject-sdk/3.0.0/myproject-sdk-3.0.0.jar does not exist
```

the entire build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'build-version'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://git.site.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public" }
        maven { url 'https://geonet.artifactoryonline.com/geonet/public-releases' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nz.org.geonet:gradle-build-version-plugin:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://git.site.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'myproject-sdk'
            groupId = 'com.myproject'
            version '3.0.0'
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // nexus maven credentials
            credentials {
                username "MY_USERNAME"
                password ""MY_PASSWORD"
            }

            if(version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "http://git.site.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
            } else {
                url "http://git.site.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Android Studio and this project is a Java project.

I don't understand the message because it says "Resource to deploy not found" and it points to a url at nexus.

I would expect a message like "Resource to deploy not found: File: c:/directory_that_doesn't_exist/whatever.jar"

Additional Information - 
The gradle tasks listed under 'All tasks' are:

```
assemble
build
buildDependents
buildNeeded
check
classes
clean
compileJava
compileTestJava
generatePomFileForMavenPublication
jar
javadoc
processResources
processTestResources
publish
publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal
publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository
publishToMavenLocal
sourceJar
test
testClasses
```

Comment: I was getting the same error because the URL to my repository was incorrect.
Have you checked whether the user you are deploying with has sufficient rights to deploy to the "releases" repository?